# How can I build node.js without some internal modules?

Tags: node.js, gyp, chakracore

I want to build a specific nodejs as a static library  without some internal module like `child_process` `dns` etc.

Is there a configurable way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the modules you don't want from [node.gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/node.gyp), remove the .js files from the `lib` folder, remove them from the `builtinLibs` array in `lib/internal/module.js` then build it.

```
{
  'variables': {
    'v8_use_snapshot%': 'false',
    'v8_trace_maps%': 0,
    'node_use_dtrace%': 'false',
    'node_use_lttng%': 'false',
    'node_use_etw%': 'false',
    'node_use_perfctr%': 'false',
    'node_no_browser_globals%': 'false',
    'node_use_v8_platform%': 'true',
    'node_use_bundled_v8%': 'true',
    'node_shared%': 'false',
    'force_dynamic_crt%': 0,
    'node_module_version%': '',
    'node_shared_zlib%': 'false',
    'node_shared_http_parser%': 'false',
    'node_shared_cares%': 'false',
    'node_shared_libuv%': 'false',
    'node_use_openssl%': 'true',
    'node_shared_openssl%': 'false',
    'node_v8_options%': '',
    'node_enable_v8_vtunejit%': 'false',
    'node_core_target_name%': 'node',
    'library_files': [
      'lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js',
      'lib/async_hooks.js',
      'lib/assert.js',
      'lib/buffer.js',
      'lib/child_process.js', //Remove this line
      'lib/console.js',
      'lib/constants.js',
      'lib/crypto.js',
      'lib/cluster.js',
      'lib/dgram.js',
      'lib/dns.js', //Remove this line too
[...]
```

Be aware that these modules are used in tests and benchmarks, and for example with `child_proccess`, in `lib/internal/v8_prof_polyfill.js` and `lib/internal/cluster/master.js`